# Pass a variable in REST POST

Tags: basex

I'm trying to pass a variable to a BaseX query according to [the docs](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/REST#Assigning_Variables), but I keep getting errors that the variable is not defined. Why?

```
Stopped at C:/Program Files (x86)/BaseX/webapp, 1/23:
[XPST0008] Undefined variable $which.
```

This is the query I'm testing with:

```
<query xmlns="http://basex.org/rest">
    <text>//greeting[position()=$which]</text>
    <variable name="which" value="0"/>
    <context><xml><greeting/></xml></context>
</query>
```

CURL to local server with default credentials

`curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -d "<query xmlns=\"http://basex.org/rest\"><text>//greeting[position()=\$which]</text><variable name=\"which\" value=\"0\"/><context><xml><greeting/></xml></context></query>" http://localhost:8984/rest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [REST documentation of BaseX](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/REST#POST_Method_2), you need to declare the variables in the prolog of your query string:

```
<query xmlns="http://basex.org/rest">
  <text>
    declare variable $which as xs:integer external;
    //greeting[position() = $which]
  </text>
  <variable name="which" value="1"/>
  <context><xml><greeting/></xml></context>
</query>
```

In addition, I have set the value of `$which` to `1` (in XPath, counting always starts with 1).